# Enviar e receber array via jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Não estou conseguindo enviar e ler um array via jQuery, poderiam me ajudar?
O meu envio está desta forma:

```
var tipoAtividade = $('#arrayTipoAtividade:checked').serialize();
```

A variável tipoAtividade está recebendo esses dados:

```
tipo_atividade%5B%5D=AGUA&tipo_atividade%5B%5D=ALMOCO
```

Como faço para ler essa variável, tipo quando uso um `foreach` para ler um array php?

Comment: Por favor, seja mais específico. O que é `#arrayTipoAtividade`? Tente fazer um exemplo com o HTML dessa parte também. Qual o tipo de requisição que está sendo enviada (GET ou POST)?

Comment: Me parece que a variavel tem algum tipo de acentuação. O correto não seria gerar algo como `tipo_atividade=AGUA&tipo_atividade=ALMOCO`?

Answer (score 0):

O PHP receberá esses dados e guardará em um vetor, veja exemplo:

```
<?php
$tipo_atividade = $_GET['tipo_atividade'];
foreach($tipo_atividade as $tipo){
    echo($tipo . '<br>');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estes caracteres estranhos são `[]` referentes ao array do html. Tente enviar estes dados por **post** ao invés de **get**, mas de qualquer forma adcione mais informações para que possamos te ajudar.